# Dummy Variable Trap And removing one Column

Tags: pandas, dummy-variable

Can anyone explain me excatly what is meant by Dummy Variable Trap?And why we want to remove one column to avoid that trap?Please provide me some links or explain this.I am not clear about this process.

Answer (score 2):

In regression analysis there's often talk about the issue of multicolinearity, which you might be familiar with already. The dummy variable trap is simply perfect colinearity between two or more variables. This can arise if, for one binary variable, two dummies are included; Imagine that you have a variable `x` which is equal to `1` when something is `True`. If you would include `x`, along with another variable `z`, which would be the opposite of `x` (i.e. `1` when that same thing is `False`), in your regression model, you would have two perfectly negatively correlated variables.

Here's a simple demonstration. Let's say your `x` is one column with `True/False` values in a `pandas` dataframe. See what happens when you use `pd.get_dummies(df.x)` below. The two dummies that are created are mirroring each other, so one of them is redundant. In simpler terms, you only need one of them since you can always guess the value of the other based on the one that you have.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [True, False]})

pd.get_dummies(df.x)
    False   True
0   0       1
1   1       0
```

The same applies if you have a categorical variable that can take on more than two values. Whether binary or not, there is always a "base scenario" that can be defined by the variation in the other case(s). This "base scenario" is therefore redundant and will only introduce perfect colinearity in the model if included.

So what's the issue with multicolinearity/linear dependence? The short answer is that if there is imperfect multicolinearity among your explanatory variables, your estimated coefficients can be distorted/biased. If there is perfect multicolinearity (which is the case with the dummy variable trap) you can't estimate your model at all; think of it like this, if you have a variable that can be perfectly explained by another variable, it means that your sample data only includes valuable information about one, not two, truly unique variables. So it would be impossible to obtain two separate coefficient estimates for the same variable.

**Further Reading**

[Multicolinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221902/what-is-an-example-of-perfect-multicollinearity)

[Dummy Variable Trap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144372/dummy-variable-trap)